# Menu items in Eclipse Juno do not work - unresponsive

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-juno

I cannot seem to click on much inside of `Eclipse Juno`. I cannot run my projects, and even when I try to do something like `Windows -> Preferences` nothing pops up for Preferences, and I get no response. I have tried `Refresh`, `Clean`, and restarting both Eclipse and my system. Still nothing. I opened Eclipse via command line and got some output, but have no idea what it means. This is what it gave me:

```
Aug 31, 2012 3:01:50 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: Copy resource /javahg.py to /tmp/1346439710466-0/javahg.py
Aug 31, 2012 3:01:50 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: Command server started: /home/jordan/Workspaces/pos
Aug 31, 2012 3:01:50 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: runcommand(22ms) status --modified --added --removed --deleted --unknown --clean 
Aug 31, 2012 3:01:50 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: Random bytes generated: #CEa68#=[;bCQXECR%&^
Aug 31, 2012 3:01:50 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: Copy resource /styles/changesets.style to /tmp/1346439710466-0/styles/changesets.style
Aug 31, 2012 3:01:50 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: Copy resource /styles/changesets-eager.style to /tmp/1346439710466-0/styles/changesets-eager.style
Aug 31, 2012 3:01:50 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: runcommand(5ms) parents --debug --style /tmp/1346439710466-0/styles/changesets.style 
Aug 31, 2012 3:01:50 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: runcommand(2ms) branch 
Aug 31, 2012 3:01:50 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: runcommand(3ms) resolve --list 
Aug 31, 2012 3:01:52 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: runcommand(19ms) parents --debug --style /tmp/1346439710466-0/styles/changesets.style 
Aug 31, 2012 3:01:52 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: Copy resource /styles/tags.style to /tmp/1346439710466-0/styles/tags.style
Aug 31, 2012 3:01:52 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: runcommand(4ms) log --debug --style /tmp/1346439710466-0/styles/tags.style --rev 899668f6b2cdd3383d823a341c746a2a29e1f841 
Aug 31, 2012 3:01:52 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: runcommand(2ms) parents --debug --style /tmp/1346439710466-0/styles/changesets.style 
Aug 31, 2012 3:01:53 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: runcommand(10ms) parents --debug --style /tmp/1346439710466-0/styles/changesets.style
Aug 31, 2012 3:02:24 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: Command server stopped: /home/jordan/Workspaces/pos
Aug 31, 2012 3:02:42 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: Command server started: /home/jordan/Workspaces/pos
Aug 31, 2012 3:02:42 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: runcommand(6ms) parents --debug --style /tmp/1346439710466-0/styles/changesets.style 
Aug 31, 2012 3:03:12 PM com.aragost.javahg.log.JULLogger info
INFO: Command server stopped: /home/jordan/Workspaces/pos
```

Anyone know what is wrong with Eclipse and how I can get my programs running again?

Comment: What's in your error log? Open the 'Error Log' view to see what exception must be happening when you attempt to view preferences.

Comment: Submit an answer and I will accept it. BY looking at the `Error Log` view I was able to see that a plugin I have been using, `Mousefeed`, was responsible for the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please open the 'Error Log' view to see what exception is happening when you attempt to view the preferences. Then you can enter a bug against or uninstall whatever plugin is causing the problem.